# ASP.NET web api 2 truncating json response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm experiencing a very weird intermittent issue with my API calls. Sometimes the **response gets truncated**.

- There isn't a pattern for how or when it gets truncated.
- Response size is 200kb and configured response limit is 20mb.

Formatters configuration:

```
private static HttpConfiguration ConfigureFormatters(this HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Formatters.Clear();
    config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    return config;
}
```

Simplified Api call:

```
[HttpGet, Route]
public IHttpActionResult Explore(int cityId)
{
    var lists = exploreBuilderService.Build(cityId);
    return Ok(lists);
}
```

`lists` type is `List<SomeModel>`. `SomeModel` is `DTO` with no circular references.

Sample response:

```
Response Headers
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2020 12:02:37 GMT
Content-Length: 290248

Data
[..., {"id":47
```

`...` are other objects in the array.
It looks like json response string is cut in a random place. Our android application fails with `MalformedJsonException` when the response comes like this. It happens once on like 5-10 requests for the same data set.

Did you encounter a problem like this? Where should I look for potential problems causing this?

Comment: How you are detecting the response is getting truncated? Can you include a sample response and truncated response?

Comment: @Ajith I edited a question with sample response

Comment: You are not using the .net core web APIs. right?

Comment: Correct, it's asp.net web api 2, .net 4.7.2

Comment: What kind of setup do you have. Which server are you using and which OS?

Comment: Windows server 2016.  IIS V. 1607 (OS build 14393.3181) 10.0.14393.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with one of our middlewares which did response interception.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone will face this problem now, like me.
But as it turned out, .Net 6

> An ASP.NET Core web API endpoint could return a truncated JSON body with a 200 response code when an exception is thrown during serialization of the object returned by the action method if a sufficient portion of the response has already been successfully serialized beforehand, so that part of the response has already been sent to the client. Fortunately, the exception will still be logged properly. The only way to reliably prevent this is to ensure that the returned object can be successfully serialized.